# Analysis Service Multidimensional - Add a new measure to existing cube

Tags: ssas, cube

To add a new measure to an existing Analysis Services Multidimensional cube I currently open the sln with SQL Server Data Tools, open the .cube file and edit the SQL in the data source view, add the measure in the measures pane and then save and deploy via the build menu.

Is this the best way to do this?  I am not sure if I can do it with without re-deploying.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to deploy only changes, this can be done by going to project properties and set the propertie "Server Mode"= "Deploy Changes Only"